# Split string in array to substrings

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple problem. I have a user input, and the text from the user input gets pushed into an array, then it is (in theory) turned into a string and then split into an array of each and every single character from the string. My question is how do I split a string in an array into an array 1 character long substrings.

```js
let plaintext = document.getElementById("plaintext");
let startB = document.getElementById("start");

let plain = [];
let encryptStorage = [];

startB.addEventListener('click', () => {
  plain.push(plaintext.value);
  plain.toString();
  encryptStorage.push(plain.split(''));
  console.log(encryptStorage);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CryptoMatic</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="plaintext" placeholder="Plaintext">
  <div id="start">
    <div id="startT">Start</div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're not asking a question here. But I can see that you should do ` encryptStorage.push(plaintext.value.split(''))`

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Ele I edited so there's a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `.toString()` or the array.  Just use the value directly:

```js
const startB = document.querySelector("#start");

const encryptStorage = [];

startB.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const plaintext = document.querySelector('#plaintext');

    encryptStorage.push(plaintext.value.split(''));
    console.log(encryptStorage);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CryptoMatic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="plaintext" placeholder="Plaintext">
                <div id="start">
                <div id="startT">Start</div></div>
       <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah didn't even notice that I don't need the `plain` array